# How to change InnerHtml to an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some one show how I can change the InnerHTML of the titles class to be the same as the alt attribute. For the actual website [jarretonions.co.za](http://jarrettonions.co.za)

Thanks

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".pic").on("click", function() {
            $(".modal").show();
            var srclong = $(this).attr("src");
            var srcshort = srclong.split("_");
            var srcextension= srclong.split(".");
            $(".modal img").attr("src", srcshort[0]+'.'+srcextension[1]);
        ************is it something like this********
                var title = $(this).attr("alt");
                $(".modal span").InnerHTML= title;

          OR 
               document.getElementByClassName('titles').innerHTML = title; 
          })
```

+

```
       echo 
                            "<div class='art'>
                            <img class='pic' src='img/".$row["name"]."_tnail.jpg' 
alt='".$row["name"]." • ".$row["year"]." • ".$row["type"]."'  
height='auto' width='100%'/>    
                            <div class='modal'>
                            <img class='big'/>
                            <span class='titles'></span>
                        </div>      
                     </div>"  
                           ;
```

Comment: This sounds like you've never used JavaScript before and are asking someone to write the code for you to copy/paste.

Comment: would definitely go for the latter. document.getElementByClassName... why use jquery at all?

Comment: Except `document.getElementByClassName` doesn't exist.

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName` exists in the same universe as `documnet.getElementsByID()` :P

Comment: I really hate people like you @melpomene you add no value to this site and to people who are trying to learn, and by your above comments you don't know what you talking about. as i have used document.getElementByClassName() in other places that have worked.

Comment: @Dylan "Write my code for me" is not people trying to learn. As for `getElementByClassName`, I checked the browser console to make sure it does in fact not exist. I believe my browser more than your claims.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQuery, you can select those elements using `$(".title")` and change them directly. Something like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pic").on("click", function() {
    $(".title").text( $(this).attr("alt") );
})});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmjtfLja/1/

Note that if you have more than one element of class `.title`, they will all change. So you may want to select the title element by id or by relative path from the clicked image.

Comment: Happy to help, @Dylan! Please mark the answer as correct, so future devs can see that it worked while skimming the page (otherwise they have to actually read this thread....)

Answer (score 0):

Realizing in advance, the danger of providing an answer that is not (superficially) fully aligned with the question, I was struck by the comment from melpomene, whom I initially thought was refering to things not existing in jquery.

melpomene is 100% correct, since getElementByClassName does not exist.
The correct syntax is getElementsByClassName.

Having said that, helloworld is also correct (syntax errors aside), since loading jquery for every little task is really redundent, and one can manipulate by class with little more half a dozen lines of pure javascript.

But, getting elements by class has dangers, since the return is a 'live' array.

For example, with dylan's original question, getting by class is only useful to return the first instance (the array length is just a guide of how many elemnts it applies to).  Therefore, for dylan to make changes as he proposed, each requires its own button.  (which also means, michael that I believe you are incorrect when you say it will affect all elements with same class name - oth, you are fully correct in noting that one should inpsect for other values (or change the class name) when running loops on the attribute).

Consider the following (on the fly class change);

```
function otf_cls_change(cls_original,cls_replace){
var a=document.getElementsByClassName(cls_original);
l=a.length;
if (l==0){return 0;}
do {
  a[0].setAttribute('class',cls_replace); 
  a=document.getElementsByClassName(cls_original);
  l=a.length;
} while (l>0);
}
```

This is effective for changing class names on the fly.

But, if we modify the code and

```
//change this a[0].setAttribute('class',cls_replace);  // to  
a[0].innerHTML='this_html';
```

It will cause the browser to hit an endless loop.

Why? because the live array returned by ElementByClass will only process the first item (even if you try to loop the array).

Therefore, while changing the class on the fly is fun and very do-able, I'd strongly suggest that using it to change any attrib that is not specific to the class id is a bad idea.

Changing the class attrib *in conjunction* with another attrib is fine.
For example,

```
a[0].innerHTML='this_html';              //do this first
a[0].setAttribute('class',cls_replace);  //then this
```

The above will work to loop class defined elements.

On a point of massive personal hypocrisy, I do get annoyed when people ask for pure javascript solutions, and then some wing nut chimes in with jquery.  I guess I'm doing the opposite here, since evidently, the question was jquery related, and here I am throwing out pure javascript.  Sorry bout that.

btw, dylan, good luck with it.  glad you bit back on the negative comment.  Too many people here are terrified of offending, and wind up get bullied.

hth,

Gary

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the feedback.
I ended up using `$(".pictitle").text( $(this).attr("alt") );` and it worked 100%
2 other questions not really related to this one, 
•1 When the code is run to load my Modal to make the image bigger, on my slowish internet it is appearing to load the image twice. I wanted to find out how i could find out if it is loading twice or not.
•2 How can i remove the main background scroll bar when the modal loads, but still allowing people to scroll down the picture. 
[link](http://jarrettonions.co.za) please look here to see what i mean or if its possible.

Comment: Hi Dylan, surpised no one dumped on you yet about asking another question in a comment.  I looked at your url and, tbh your code needs work and could be more efficient at managing bandwidth.  I snagged a couple of your images and put together some thoughts based on what I think you are trying to do.  This location will be available for the next couple of weeks if you want to take a look.  The code is fully exposed and should also cover your  title from alt question, as well as changing classes on the fly.
[link](http://www.windgatesoftwarellc.com/stack/dylan/index.htm)